# Unit test membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-membership, app-config

I'm integration testing an MVC controller that uses the membership API.  I've added my app.config below.  The tests attempt to run, but when they make a call to the api, they return null.  I inspect the Membership object, and it doesn't contain my connection string, it contains the default one that comes from the machine.config.  It also does not pick up my configured application name.  It seems to me that I have an issue with my app.config to the point where the membership api is not picking up its settings.

Can anyone spot the error?

```
var usr = Membership.GetUser(AValidGuid);  This is always null!!!!


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="membership" type="System.Web.Configuration.MembershipSection, System.Web" />
        <section name="roleManager" type="System.Web.Configuration.RoleManagerSection, System.Web" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add connectionString="server=;user id=;password=;database=" name="SqlProvider" />
      </connectionStrings>

      <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
          <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"></remove>
          <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="SqlProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/test" />
        </providers>
      </membership>
      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProvider">
        <providers>
          <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"></remove>
          <add connectionStringName="SqlProvider" applicationName="/test" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </providers>
      </roleManager>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ah Ha!  I forgot to wrap the membership and role provider sections in <system.web />

Answer (score 0):

Your app.config will need to be updated for the application executing the test.  Is that what the posted app.config applies to?  I know that's a basic thing but a lot of people get hung up on which config is being utilized by the test runner.

Comment: I added an app.config to the test project.  It picks up the connectionStrings if I do ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["blah"].ConnectionString